# How do I retrieve objects in Ninject kernel parameters that need in constructor for initialization

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, compact-framework, ioc-container

I'm using as Ninject IoC.

My question is how to retrieve an object that requires a parameter in the constructor.

Below a sample code:

```
//Interface for connection
public interface IConnection
{
    IDbConnection CurrentConnection { get; }
}

//Concret connection
public class MyConnection : IConnection
{
    public MyConnection(IDbConnection nativeConnection){  }
}

//Module ninject
class Module : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IConnection>().To<MyConnection>().InSingletonScope();
    }
}

//Native connection
var sqlConn = new SqlCeConnection();

//Ninject kernel
var ker = new StandardKernel(new Module());
return ker.Get<IConnection>(); //How can I pass as parameters to the constructor of class "MyConnection"??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add/define a binding for IDbConnection. Then Ninject will pass that automatically to the constructor.
For example

```
Bind<IDbConnection>.To<SqlCeConnection>();
```

Or you can have a constant in your module

```
private static readonly SqlConnection = new SqlCeConnection();
```

And then bind the interface to that

```
Bind<IDbConnection>.ToConstant(SqlConnection);
```

Best check [this](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki) page for more information.

**Update**

I don't think it's a very sophisticated design. But if you want you can directly pass a parameter to the constructor.

```
ker.Get<IConnection>(new ConstructorArgument("nativeConnection",yourConnection));
```

I don't know why exactly you need that, and how it works in singleton scope though.

Comment: but its ok and besides I had other connection parameter settings, as a string for example:  

´//Concret connection
public class MyConnection : IConnection
{
   public MyConnection(IDbConnection nativeConnection, string str){  }
}´
@treze